# Multivariable limit - perhaps a trickier problem I am stuck on.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve the following limit:

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^4y^4}{(x^2 + y^4)^3}$

(This is a more challenging problem from Folland Calculus, it seems).

I am pretty sure this limit does not exist (however, this is just a guess, and I am not 100% sure.)

I am trying to approach via the paths y = mx and x = my but... they don't seem to work. I have tried simpler cases such as x = 0 and y = 0.

Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One may observe that, as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, with $x>0$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$, one gets
$$
\frac{x^4y^4}{(x^2 + y^4)^3}=\frac18,
$$ on the other hand, as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, with $y>0$ and $x=\sqrt{y}$, one gets
$$
\frac{x^4y^4}{(x^2 + y^4)^3}=\frac{y^3}{\left(1+y^3\right)^3}\to 0,
$$ thus the limit of the given function does *not* exist.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @MH1993 You are welcome.

Comment: Concise and complete.  +1

Answer (score 4):

If $$f(x,y) = \frac{x^4 y^4}{(x^2 + y^4)^3},$$ this suggests that when $x^2$ and $y^4$ tend to $0$ at the same rate, i.e., if we let $x^2 = y^4$, then we find $$f(y^2,y) = \frac{(y^2)^4 y^4}{((y^2)^2+y^4)^3} = \frac{y^{12}}{(2y^4)^3} = \frac{1}{8}.$$  This is the desired path that demonstrates the limit does not exist at $(0,0)$, since another choice such as along the line $(x,0)$ gives a limit of $0$.

Comment: Right. I did get 1/8 for the first bit but I did not think of how to get another path that was different.. thank you.

Comment: Clear and concise.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Use polar coordinates :
$$\frac{x^4y^4}{(x^2+y^4)^3} = \frac{r^8\cos^4\theta\sin^4\theta}{r^6(\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta)^3} = r^2\frac{\cos^4\theta\sin^4\theta}{(\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta)^3}$$
Now the problem remaining is : is the fraction bounded or not ? You have, for $\theta\ne\frac\pi2\mod\pi$ :
$$\frac{\cos^4\theta\sin^4\theta}{(\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta)^3} = \frac{\cos^4\theta\sin^4\theta}{\cos^6\theta\left(1+r^2\frac{\sin^4\theta}{\cos^2\theta}\right)^4}$$
So if you go to $0$ following the curve of equation $r=\cos\theta$, for example (this is a circle tangent to the $y$ axis at the origin), you have :
$$\frac{x^4y^4}{(x^2+y^4)^3} = \cos^2\theta\frac{\cos^4\theta\sin^4\theta}{\cos^6\theta(1+\sin^4\theta)}\xrightarrow[\theta\to\frac\pi2]{}\frac12\ne0$$
So your function is not continuous at the origin, as you suspected.

Comment: I really don't understand how/when to use polar co-odinates. Also you may have an error - the denominator is to a power of 3.

Comment: @MH1993 : Oups, sorry. Correcting...

Comment: @MH1993 : when you see powers, products and quotient, polar coordinates are usually helpful, even if here, the solution given by Olivier is clearly sufficient :-)

Comment: Yes, Nicolas is right.

Comment: How did you determine the variable r (I assuming this is the radius)? Is it the sum of the exponents? What's the "meaning" behind this? And thanks for your comment! It's always nice to have different solutions. :-)

Comment: What do you mean, "determine" ? In general, choosing polar coordinates is just using the euclidian norm : $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ which simplifies the condition $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ into $r\to0$.

Comment: If you mean when I said "let's use $r=\cos\theta$", I just wanted to make the denominator as close to $\cos^6\theta$ as possible.

Comment: Oh I see. Gotcha!

Answer (score 0):

For $x=t\cdot \cos(\theta)$ and $y=\sqrt{t\sin(\theta)}$ we have 
$$
\frac{x^4y^4}{(x^2+y^4)^3}=\frac{t^4\cos^4(\theta) t^2\sin^2(\theta)}{(t^2\cos^2(\theta)+t^2\sin^2(\theta))^3}
=
\cos^4(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)
$$